# NSFetchRequest returns wrong entity type

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, core-data

My Core Data app has two entities: "Note" and "Marker". The Note entity has a 1-to-many relationship to markers (ie. A note contains many markers). I have a fetchedRequestController which is responsible for fetching all the "Note" entities. After creating 1 note and 1 marker (which belongs to that note) I get an error because the fetchedRequestController fetches both the Marker and Note. The Note is expected but the Marker should not be fetched.

Here is my fetched request controller

```
    TCModel *model = [TCModel sharedModel];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [model managedObjectContext];
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSParameterAssert(entity);
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                              initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                              managedObjectContext:context
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                              cacheName:@"Root"];
    NSParameterAssert(controller);
    self.fetchedResultsController = controller;
    controller.delegate = self;
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [controller performFetch:&error];
    if ( success == NO )
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch!");
        NSParameterAssert(nil);
    }
```

The objects are created using two helper methods and then saved using a third

```
- (TCNote *)newNote
{
    TCNote *note = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    note.creationDate = [NSDate new];
    return note;
}

- (TCMarker *)newMarker
{
    TCMarker *marker = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Marker"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    return marker;
}

- (void)_save
{
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"Saving");
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: Error = %@", error);
    }
}
```

Here is the console output:

2013-01-03 17:41:12.062 timecode[10269:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA

2013-01-03 17:41:12.063 timecode[10269:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNOTEDATE, t0.ZSCENEDESCRIPTION, t0.ZSCENETITLE, t0.ZTIMECODEDATE, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZPARENT, t0.Z1_PARENT FROM ZNOTE t0

2013-01-03 17:41:12.064 timecode[10269:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0005s

2013-01-03 17:41:12.064 timecode[10269:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0011s for 2 rows.

Comment: Updated & approved answers. Wasn't aware of that before ;)

Comment: Just noticed that my SQLite schema doesnt have a table for the Marker entities. Not sure why that would be the case. There is a ZNOTE table but not a ZMARKER one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined *Note* as "parent entity" of *Marker*, i.e. *Marker* is a "child entity" of *Note*:

[image]

That means that every *Marker* object is also a *Note* object (same as with class and subclass). Fetching all objects of the *Note* entity does therefore also return the objects of the *Marker* entity.

The SQLite file contains in this case only one table ZNOTE, which has columns for the properties of *Note* and for the additional properties of *Marker*.

So if you don't really need *Marker* to be a child entity of *Note*, just set the "Parent Entity" to "No Parent Entity".

Comment: I completely misunderstood the 'parent' property! Thought it meant parent node. Muchos gracis :D